# Algorithms for combining Bayesian networks?

Tags: bayesian, algorithms, bayesian-network, dag

Are there any algorithms for combining multiple Bayesian networks? For example, let's say I have 5 variables A, B, C, D and E, and I build 5 Bayesian networks on different random subsets of these, let's say:

1. A, B, C
2. C, D
3. A, E, D
4. B, E, A
5. A, D

Is it possible to recover a single BN that is an aggregate of these 5 individual BNs in the general case?

Comment: Could you clarify how you are building the individual  networks and what is the purpose of the combination?